# uploading image to server php to python

Tags: php, python, base64

I am converting my code from php to python and want to find the equivalent
in python. My android application sends a base64 encrypted image and folder name. The script should decode it and save it to my server.

The php is

```
<?php
    // Get image string posted from Android App
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
    // Get file name posted from Android App
    $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
    // Decode Image
    $binary=base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    // Images will be saved under 'www/img/uplodedimages' folder
    $file = fopen('/home1/test/public_html/img/'.$filename.'.jpg', 'wb');
    if($file != true)
    {
    echo'Error uploading image';
    }
    else{
     // Create File
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
    echo 'Image upload successful';
    }
?>
```

My attempt to convert to python is bellow

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import cgi
import base64
import json

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"

d = {}
arguments = cgi.FieldStorage()
base = arguments.getvalue('image')
filename = arguments.getvalue('filename')   

binary = base.b64decode('base64')
file = open('/home1/test/public_html/img/%s.jpg', 'wb') % filename
if file != True:
    d['success'] = 0
    d['message'] = 'Error uploading image'
    print json.dumps(d)
else:
    file.write(file, binary)
    file.close()
    d['success'] = 1
    d['message'] = 'Upload Successful'
    print json.dumps(d)
```

I have never used I/O With python so I am new with it. When running the output is blank.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import cgi
import base64
import simplejson

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"

d = {}
arguments = cgi.FieldStorage()
data = arguments.getvalue('image')
filename = arguments.getvalue('filename')

binary = base64.b64decode(data)
file = open('/home1/test/public_html/img/%s.jpg' % filename, 'wb')

if file != True:
    d['success'] = 0
    d['message'] = 'Error uploading image'
    print simplejson.dumps(d)
else:
    file.write(file, binary)
    file.close()
    d['success'] = 1
    d['message'] = 'Upload Successful'
    print simplejson.dumps(d)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have made the change and it is still throwing a 500 server error

Comment: actually in my other scripts i import json (got 500 error to go away imported wrong) and json.dumps(d) worked. however the output is blank now

Comment: And sorry LogApi is a seperate Api I created and shouldnt even be imported here.

Comment: Since this is a raw HTTP response, you need to add a valid protocol header  like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` before the content type. PHP does this automatically.

Comment: how would I add the header?

Comment: Print it out like you did the content type. `print 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'`. Just make sure it's first.

Comment: Added full code. You were decoding the base64 data incorrectly. It will still return an empty page, but that's only because there's no input (you can add print statements right before and right after the decode) . Try using this with your android app. And I was wrong about the HTTP header.